# Use observable value to make request that returns another observable and push to Kafka

Tags: typescript, rxjs, functional-programming, observable, nestjs

I am using NestJS and the in-built `HttpModule` in a `Service` with the end-goal of pushing the value returned from an `Observable<AxiosResponse<any>>` to a Kafka topic.

My `Observables` are responses from an `HttpService` (provider of `HttpModule`) that invoke JSON-RPC requests (HTTP POST requests), for example as follows:

```
getInfo(): Observable<AxiosResponse<any>> {
  return this.httpService.post(this.url, { "method" : "somemethod" } )
}
```

I know it is not considered good practice to store values from an `Observable` since it is not in line with the functional programming paradigm.

However, what if I need to store a value from the `AxiosResponse<any>` and feed this into another `httpService.post` request? How should I go about doing this?

I have tried using a separate function in my `Service` which returns an `Observable`, and I would like to use `getInfo()` inside this function and subscribe to the result, so I can pass a value from the first `Observable` into the second `Observable` in this way:

```
getMoreInfo(): Observable<AxiosResponse<any>> {
        this.getInfo().pipe(
            take(1))
                .subscribe(
                    (response) => {
                        return this.httpService.post(this.url, {
                            "method" : "othermethod",
                            "params": {
                                "myparam" : response.data.result.param
                            }
                        })
                    }
                )
    }
```

However, because the `return` is in the scope of the first `Observable`, my function is invalid because it does not have a valid `return` type of `Observable<AxiosResponse<any>>`.

I wanted to check whether the nesting logic was correct, and indeed it was since I can do this:

```
getMoreInfo() {
        this.getInfo().pipe(
            take(1))
                .subscribe(
                    (response) => {
                        this.httpService.post(this.url, {
                            "method" : "othermethod",
                            "params": {
                                "stringparam" : response.data.result.param.toString()
                            }
                        }).subscribe((secondResponse) => { console.log(secondResponse) }                         
                    }
                )
    }
```

Because I want my NestJs `Controller` to `subscribe` to my `Observables` and only let the `Service` create `Observables`, I have to `return` an `Observable<AxiosResponse<any>>`. How can I do this?

In effect, I solely want to take the output from an `Observable` and pass that into another function. If I know how to do this I can pass it to the function responsible for pushing to `Kafka` accordingly, and I would be able to pass the value to the `getMoreInfo()` function.

Comment: Lookup `mergeMap` or `switchMap` - it appears you want to have a sequence of http calls. Those pipeable operators are easier to use than multiple subscribes

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in that direction @Drenai. Indeed, writing it like in my below comment works.

```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @Drenai for pointing me in the right direction!

I was able to solve it using the `mergeMap` operator.

The solution looks like this:

```
getMoreInfo() {
        this.getInfo().pipe(
            mergeMap((res) => this.httpService.post(this.url, {
                "method" : "somemethod",
                "params" : {
                    "stringparam" : res.data.result.myparam.toString()
                }
            })
        ))
    }
```